# Is IBS a psychosomatic disorder?

Tags: mental-health, digestion, irritable-bowel-syndrome, psychosomatic-illness

Is irritable bowel syndrome a psychosomatic disorder? Given that people with IBS often suffer from depression or anxiety and that the colon is partly controlled by the nervous system?

Comment: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/371/6527/333